# Form Group Has No name angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formgroups

I want to loop through my formgroups and then identify which ones are valid, and then add the invalid from groups to a new array. However i am having trouble grabbing the name value for each formgroup.

```html
 this.applicationFormArray = new FormGroup({   
        selectAppFormGroup:this.selectAppFormGroup = new FormGroup({
        }),
        generalAppFormGroup:this.generalAppFormGroup = new FormGroup({
        }),
        fileModeFormGroup:this.fileModeFormGroup = new FormGroup({
        }),
        accessListFormGroup:this.accessListFormGroup = new FormGroup({
        })
    });

    this.applicationFormGroup.addControl('applicationFormArray', this.applicationFormArray);
```

```html
checkValidity() {
        for (let c of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.applicationFormArray.controls)) {
            if(!this.applicationFormArray.controls[c].valid) {
                var invalidFormGroups = new Array;
                var grabFormGroups = console.log(this.applicationFormArray.controls[c].get('?????'));
                invalidFormGroups.push(grabFormGroups);
            }
        } 
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Root form group has no name.
Wrap them into another 'root' form group to give them names.

Comment: i tried that but the form groups still come out without a name when looping through them. Updated above

Comment: You can access name from parent using loops:
`g: FormGroup;`
`Object.entries(g.parent.controls).find(([,v]) => v === g)[0]`

Comment: this would allow me to have access to the names within the parent formgroup however this would always show the whole collection. I want to only select the valid formgroups.